# How does this prime number checking function work

Tags: scala, recursion

Can anybody please help me how this code works,
I am not getting it by myself, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Prime number in scala using recusion:

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = {
  def isPrimeUntil(t: Int): Boolean =
    if (t<=1) true
    else n%t != 0 && isPrimeUntil(t-1)

  isPrimeUntil(n/2)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean how the algorithm is working or how the nested function is executed?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the square root of `n` (rounded) instead of `n/2`?

Answer (score 2):

The number `n` is prime if and only if there's no number `t` such that `t != 1, t!= n, n % t = 0`.

So, if you find some number from `2` to `n-1` such that `n % t = 0`, `n` is composite, otherwise it is prime.
One more thing, you may see that there's no need to search for divisors among the  numbers greater than `n/2`.

So, all the algorithm does is checks `n % d` for each `t` from `n/2` to `2`. As soon as it is found, the algorithms stops ans says **it's composite** (returns `False`). Otherwise it gets to `t = 1` and assures **the number is prime** (returns `True`).

Just to mention, it's enough to consider the numbers from `ceil(sqrt(n))` to `2`, which results in better time complexity (O(sqrt(n)) vs O(n)).

Answer (score 1):

```
isPrime(7) --> isPrimeUntil(3) --> (3 <= 1)? no
                                   (7%3 != 0)? yes
               isPrimeUntil(2) --> (2 <= 1)? no
                                   (7%2 != 0)? yes
               isPrimeUntil(1) --> (1 <= 1)? yes
```

`isPrime(7)` is **true**. No divisor was found between 1 and 7/2.

```
isPrime(9) --> isPrimeUntil(4) --> (4 <= 1)? no
                                   (9%4 != 0)? yes
               isPrimeUntil(3) --> (3 <= 1)? no
                                   (9%3 != 0)? no
```

`isPrime(9)` is **false**. Found that 9 is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local Scala REPL, you should paste this function in there and play around with it. If not, there's always Scastie. I made a [Scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Umzom5odSLijfdmxMeBB6A), in which I changed the formatting to my liking, added comments and a demo range.

There are examples of Scala that make it look almost like Malbolge. This one is not that bad.

Let's follow it through with a composite number like 102. Calling `isPrime(102)` causes `isPrimeUntil(51)` to be invoked (as 51 is half 102). Since 51 is greater than 1, the nested function calculated `102 % 51`, which is 0, so, by "short-circuit evaluation" of logical AND, the nested function should return false.

Now let's try it with 103. Calling `isPrime(103)` causes `isPrimeUntil(51)` to be invoked (as 51 is half 103 and the remainder of 1 is simply discarded). Since 51 is greater than 1, the nested function calculated `103 % 51`, which is 1, so the nested function calls itself as `primeUntil(50)`. Since 50 is greater than 1, the... so on and so forth until calling itself as `primeUntil(1)`. Since `t == 1`, `primeUntil` returns true and the recursion stops.

This gives the wrong answer for negative composite numbers. Plus, as others have mentioned, it is inefficient to start the recursion at *n*/2. This would be an improvement:

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = {
  def isPrimeUntil(t: Int): Boolean = {
    if (t <= 1) true else n % t != 0 && isPrimeUntil(t - 1)
  }
  isPrimeUntil(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(n))).toInt)
}
```

Hmm... it's still giving the wrong answer for −1, 0, 1. But hopefully now you understand this function.

Comment: can you please explain me how this code works                                             def Factorial(n: Int): Int =
    if (n <= 1) 1
    else {
      println("computing factorial of " + n + " - 1st i need factorial of " + (n - 1))
  val result = n * Factorial(n - 1)
  println("computed factorial of " + n)
  result
}
  println(Factorial(5))

Comment: It's kind of self-explanatory already. Play around with it in this Scastie snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kpRwgmdPSLi5Tj4QStUQQA

Comment: Here i dont understand why 2nd println statement prints all numbers

Comment: Then I suggest you work through it with pencil and paper.